# Accessing data inside of an FFI pointer (libtcod)

Tags: ruby, ffi, libtcod

I'm using the ruby port of libtcod, which [binds to the C functions](https://github.com/mispy/libtcod/blob/master/lib/libtcod/bindings.rb#L178). In particular, I'm trying to use this function:

```
tcod_function :TCOD_sys_check_for_event, [ :int, :pointer, :pointer ], :int
```

I'm doing so like this:

```
mouse = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:int, 5)
keyboard = nil
event = TCOD.sys_check_for_event(TCOD::EVENT_ANY, keyboard, mouse)
```

(FYI, I'm just guessing at the size of the MemoryPointer, which may be my first problem. I'm not sure how to find the actual size it requires.)

My issue now is that I'm not sure how to get the information I need out of `mouse`. The [C](https://bitbucket.org/libtcod/libtcod/src/c6de03fb9745e9818e99b35d35cab970903e4895/src/sys_sdl_c.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#sys_sdl_c.c-1355) for this function describes a beautiful looking `tcod_mouse`, which I'd love to get access to.

Comment: I just found (this)[https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Structs] and will update my question once I figure that out.